# Assign a function's returned IEnumerable<MovingAverage> value to another object

Tags: c#

I am calling this function from another function:

```
        private static IEnumerable<MovingAverage> SimpleMovingAverage(
        IEnumerable<IexTradingStock> queue, int period)
        .
        . (omitted code) 
        .
    {   return movingAverages;
```

This is the function that calls MovingAverage:

```
                MovingAverage SMA = new MovingAverage();
            SMA = SimpleMovingAverage(stocks, period);
```

I get an error on this line "SMA = SimpleMovingAverage(stocks, period);"  The error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'myBackEnd.Models.MovingAverage' an explicit conversions e xists (are you missing a cast)

Comment: What is the return type of the SimpleMovingAverage function, and what is the type of SMA?

Comment: The error tells you precisely what's going wrong.

Comment: As a side point, there's no point setting SMA to a new of anything, if you're going to update it in the next line.

Comment: Why is `SMA` of type `MovingAverage` when `SimpleMovingAverage` returns a 
"collection" (0 or more) of `MovingAverage`? _If that doesn't make sense, it is like you are trying to assign a carton of eggs to a variable that expects a **single** egg._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function return type should be IEnumerable not a single object. When you have declared this function you set its return type as IEnumerable but when in your return statement your are returning a single object of MovingAverage. The returned object should be same as you have declared your return type. Secondly when you are getting the list from SimpleMovingAverage(stocks, period); and setting the list in MovingAverage SMA = new MovingAverage(); is wrong. It should be.

```
IEnumerable<MovingAverage>  SMA = SimpleMovingAverage(stocks, period);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign an `IEnumerable<MovingAverage>` (a collection of `MovingAverage`) to a single `MovingAverage` variable : it is impossible.

You could either declare your SMA variable as an `IEnumerable<MovingAverage>` like this :

```
IEnumerable<MovingAverage>  SMA = SimpleMovingAverage(stock, period);
```

or let the compiler guess the appropriate type using var :

```
var SMA = SimpleMovingAverage(stock, period);
```

or, if you really want to return a single element, for example get the first one like this :

```
MovingAverage SMA = SimpleMovingAverage(stock, period).FirstOrDefault();
```